# Want two dynamically created input values to be saved in one mysql row using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, dynamic

what i want is when a user clicks a link it should automatically create **two** text box's at a time and from which we can click and create unlimited numbers of textboxs which when submitted it should save all the dynamically created textbox two text box's in a row.

meaning textboxA textboxB

in this manner......

I found a code on net which works very similar to that how i wanted...but instead of two textboxs it creates only one textbox at a time when clicked the link  First i'll give u the full original code...

1) index.php

```
<?php 
//Include the database class
require("classes/db.class.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' 
                + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />' );

    });
});
</script> 

<body>

<?php
//If form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {

    //create instance of database class
    $db = new mysqldb();
    $db->select_db();

    //Insert static values into users table
    $sql_user = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) );  
    $result_user = $db->query($sql_user);


    //Check if user has actually added additional fields to prevent a php error
    if ($_POST['fields']) {

        //get last inserted userid
        $inserted_user_id = $db->last_insert_id();

        //Loop through added fields
        foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value ) {

            //Insert into websites table
            $sql_website = sprintf("INSERT INTO websites (Website_URL) VALUES ('%s')",
                                   mysql_real_escape_string($value) );  
            $result_website = $db->query($sql_website);
            $inserted_website_id = $db->last_insert_id();


            //Insert into users_websites_link table
            $sql_users_website = sprintf("INSERT INTO users_websites_link (UserID, WebsiteID) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                                   mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_user_id),
                                   mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_website_id) );  
            $result_users_website = $db->query($sql_users_website);

        }

    } else {

        //No additional fields added by user

    }
    echo "<h1>User Added, <strong>" . count($_POST['fields']) . "</strong> website(s) added for this user!</h1>";

    //disconnect mysql connection
    $db->kill();
}
?>

<?php if (!isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) { ?>
    <h1>New User Signup</h1>
    <form name="test" method="post" action="">
        <label for="name">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <label for="name">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /> 

        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <div id="container">
            <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>&raquo; Add your favourite links.....</span></a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <input id="go" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

2) db.class.php

```
<?php
class mysqldb {

    /*
    FILL IN YOUR DATABASE DETAILS BEFORE RUNNING THE EXAMPLE
    */

    var $hostname = "localhost";
    var $username = "root";
    var $password = "mypassword";
    var $database = "unlimited";


    function db_connect() {
        $result = mysql_connect($this->hostname,$this->username,$this->password); 
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Connection to database server at: '.$this->hostname.' failed.';
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }


    function select_db() {
        $this->db_connect();
        if (!mysql_select_db($this->database)) {
            echo 'Selection of database: '.$this->database.' failed.';
            return false;
        }
    }

    function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed: $query<br><br>" . mysql_error());
        return $result;
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }

    function fetch_array($result) {
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }

    function num_rows($result) {
        return mysql_num_rows($result);
    }

    function last_insert_id() {
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }

    function kill() {
        mysql_close();
    }

} 
?>
```

3) css.css

```
html, input {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;}
body { width: 500px; margin: 50px auto 0 auto; display: block;}
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; color: #333; }
input { font-size: 0.9em; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc;  margin: 0; display: block;}
a { text-decoration: none; color: #666; font-weight: bold; }
a:hover { color: #ff0000; }
#divTxt { width:400px; padding: 5px;  }
p a img { border: none; vertical-align: middle; }
.spacer {clear: both; height: 10px; }
.btn { width: 90px; font-weight: bold; }
#container { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 2px; }
.clear {overflow: hidden;width: 100%;
}
```

4) **JQUERY.js**

With this code i am only allowed to dynamically create one textbox when clicked the link as i said earlier, so to make it for my use as i wanted to have two textbox's i have edited the jquery part in the `index.php` page as below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' 
                + '<label for="fields[]' + '">Colour</label><input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><label for="fields2[]' + '">Quantity</label><input id="field2_' + count + '" name="fields2[]' + '" type="text" /><br />');
    });
});
</script>
```

Till here i am successfull... but the main problem is I cannot save them both the two textbox's in a row in mysql table..

Please review this code and reply me if u get any answers.....

I'll surely click the green arrow for the working answer as accepted answer..

Please HELP guys......

Comment: So far, you tried and more textbox when user click the link..

Comment: yes it creates two text box's at a time when user clicks the link. but i am unable to save all the text box values in my mysql table

Comment: okies. Then after submitting your form with more than text box groups, just check it out what you are getting from the post values. like that, `print_r($_POST);` then reply.

Comment: And one more thing, check the `POST values` like that, 
`if( isset($_POST['fields']) )`

Comment: Array ( [name] => SAMSON [password] => 4854 [fields] => Array ( [0] => red [1] => yellow ) [fields2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [btnSubmit] => Signup ) 1

Comment: Fine. But you write a logic for `$_POST['fields']` only, not for `$_POST['fields2'] (ie, 2nd text box)`. And First insert logic is right. Now change your approach for insert `website value` without using `sprintf('')`

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO websites (Website_URL) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' " );

            $result_website = $db->query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' 
                + '<label for="field_'+count+'_1">Name</label><input id="field_'+count+'_1" name="fields[]['name']" type="text" /><label for="field2_'+count+'_2">URL</label><input id="field2_'+count+'_2" name="fields[]['url']" type="text" /><br />');
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
        //Insert into websites table
        $sql_website = sprintf("INSERT INTO websites (Website_Name,Website_URL) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                               mysql_real_escape_string($value['name']),
                               mysql_real_escape_string($value['url']) );  
        $result_website = $db->query($sql_website);
        $inserted_website_id = $db->last_insert_id();
```

I am assuming that the 1st column is Website_Name and the 2nd column is Website_URL

---

**P.S.** : You've said it creates two text boxes, which means there should be two table fields where you want to add those two values. But in your MySQL query, there is only one column insert.

```
"INSERT INTO websites (Website_URL) VALUES ('%s')"
```

Specify the 2nd column name to answer your question correctly.

Comment: I get this error     Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 52

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 53

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 52

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 53

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 52

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 53

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 52

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in C:\xampp\htdocs\americanopticsmanager\ALL TESTING FILES\test unlimited\index.php on line 53